# How to fix a particular column value while moving a table row up or down in jquery

Tags: javascript, css

I am facing a problem with a functionality of moving a table row up or down. In my code the rows are moving up and down perfectly but in that I don't want to change a particular column value. In my case it will be the right most column before the button columns. Please have a look of my existing code and help me solve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
table.myTable {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table.myTable tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table.myTable tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
button.uparrow{
    background-color:#FFCC66;
}
button.downarrow{
    background-color:#66FF66;
}
</style>
<script>
function get_previoussibling(n)
{
    x=n.previousSibling;
    while (x.nodeType!=1)
      {
      x=x.previousSibling;
      }
    return x;
} 

function get_nextsibling(n)
{
    x=n.nextSibling;
    while ( x != null && x.nodeType!=1)
      {
      x=x.nextSibling;
      }
    return x;
} 
function MoveUp()
    {
        var table,
            row = this.parentNode;

        while ( row != null ) {
            if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
                break;
            }
            row = row.parentNode;
        }
        table = row.parentNode;
        table.insertBefore ( row, get_previoussibling( row ) );
    }

    function MoveDown()
    {
        var table,
            row = this.parentNode;

        while ( row != null ) {
            if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
                break;
            }
            row = row.parentNode;
        }
        table = row.parentNode;
        table.insertBefore ( row, get_nextsibling ( get_nextsibling( row ) ) );
    }
</script>
<title>Moving Row Up/Down</title>
</head>

<body>
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
    <tr >
    <td></td>
    <td>Justine</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td style="width:30px;"><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td style="width:30px;"><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Michael</td> 
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Robert</td> 
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Samuel</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>30</td> 
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Clifa</td>
    <td>Female</td> 
    <td>34</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

e.g. if I am click on the up button or down button of 3rd row, In my case entire row is interchanging position with either previous row or next row for up and down respectively. Whereas for up button 21 should not change the place with 24 and for down 30 should not change the place with 24.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? And why is it tagged jQuery, there's no jQuery at all in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this while following your current pattern is to swap the text content of the target elements when switching.

Quick Example: https://codepen.io/davidatthepark/pen/NvVEaP?editors=1010

```js
function get_previoussibling(n) {
  x = n.previousSibling;
  while (x.nodeType != 1) {
    x = x.previousSibling;
  }
  return x;
}

function get_nextsibling(n) {
  x = n.nextSibling;
  while (x != null && x.nodeType != 1) {
    x = x.nextSibling;
  }
  return x;
}
function MoveUp() {
  var table,
    row = this.parentNode,
    rowText,
    previousSibling;

  while (row != null) {
    if (row.nodeName == "TR") {
      break;
    }
    row = row.parentNode;
  }
  table = row.parentNode;
  previousSibling = get_previoussibling(row);
  rowText = row.children[3].textContent;
  row.children[3].textContent = previousSibling.children[3].textContent;
  previousSibling.children[3].textContent = rowText;
  
  table.insertBefore(row, previousSibling);
}

function MoveDown() {
  var table,
    row = this.parentNode,
    rowText,
    nextSibling;

  while (row != null) {
    if (row.nodeName == "TR") {
      break;
    }
    row = row.parentNode;
  }
  table = row.parentNode;
  nextSibling = get_nextsibling(row);
  rowText = row.children[3].textContent;
  row.children[3].textContent = nextSibling.children[3].textContent;
  nextSibling.children[3].textContent = rowText;
  
  table.insertBefore(row, get_nextsibling(get_nextsibling(row)));
}
```

```css
table.myTable {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table.myTable tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table.myTable tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
button.uparrow{
    background-color:#FFCC66;
}
button.downarrow{
    background-color:#66FF66;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Justine</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td style="width:30px;"><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td style="width:30px;"><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Samuel</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Clifa</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td><button class="uparrow" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button class="downarrow" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Its really working fine and as per my desire. But can you please check once while for the top element if clicked "Up" button and for extreme bottom element if clicked "Down" button its showing error...